# Google App Engine Cache Size

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

When I run my application on GAE, I retrieved the cache info.

```
    {'hits': 672148648L, 'items': 2L, 'bytes': 18446744073709513520L, 'oldest_item_age': 0L, 'misses': 6716984L, 'byte_hits': 44238386603L}
```

I use my memcache extensively. 
Is it true that cache size allocated for my application is so large  ? 
This is the code which i use to retrieve the stats

```
cache_stats = memcache.get_stats()
s = str(cache_stats)
self.response.out.write(s + "\n\n")
```

Comment: what logic are you using to retrieve the cache info that returns a JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

16 million terabytes seems outlandish.

Even for The Google.

Answer (score 1):

Nick Johnson of Google [said](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine@googlegroups.com/msg19950.html) that "the [memcache] space available to a given app will vary based on a number of factors, including its traffic". The amount you're quoting doesn't sound right, but if it is - tell us your secrets...